# canvas.getContext is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive, html5-canvas

I have written a simple template for a AngularJs directive:

```
<div class="circle">
    <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

My directive has the following look:

```
MobileApp.directive('circle', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            ...
            var canvas = elem.find('canvas');
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

And the usage of that is simple enough:

```
<circle/>
```

I am getting an error when trying to call a method `getContext('2d')`:

> TypeError: `canvas.getContext` is not a function

The `canvas` instance is selected and its JSON representation looks

```
{
  "0": {},
  "length": 1,
  "prevObject": {
    "0": {},
    "context": {},
    "length": 1
  },
  "context": {},
  "selector": "canvas"
}
```

I have already read about all related questions here, but the answer hasn't been found. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I create [a little plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/mOU0ZucRSZzdWxVmTFIZ?p=preview). In your sample i don't understand the relation between directive and template. Have you missing to add template property ? What i do in plunker :

Define template :

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    template: '<div><canvas></canvas></div>',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        var canvas = elem.find('canvas');
        console.log(canvas);
        var ctx = canvas[0].getContext('2d');
        console.log(canvas, ctx);
    }
}
```

Get canvas from the object that return by find method :

```
var ctx = canvas[0].getContext('2d');
```

And the use :

```
<circle></circle>
```

Comment: I'm using `templateUrl: '/tabs/home/circle/circle.tmpl.html'`

Comment: Ok, so just use canvas[0].getContext('2d');

Comment: when I print it out by `alert(JSON.stringify(elem.find('canvas')[0]))`, I received `{}`, but when I use your way, it works fine

Comment: I think there is no json representation of a dom element. Don't use JSON.stringify on element. Use  elem.find('canvas')[0].toString() the result will be [object HTMLCanvasElement]

Comment: I will be aware, you saved me hours (I am a new in front-end development), thank you

Answer (score 1):

Replace  `var canvas = elem.find('canvas');`
by  `var canvas = elem.find('canvas')[0];`